# Arguments HTTP Post c#

Tags: c#, http, http-post, httpwebrequest, webrequest

I am making an HTTP POST method to get data. I have an idea to create a method to get a specific arguments but when I don't have idea to get the arguments taken. In HTTP GET, arguments are in the URL and is more easy to get the arguments. How do I create a method to take all the data in HTTP Post? In PHP for example when you show the var $_POST you show all data in the body post. How can I do this in C#?

My method is this:

```
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public IHttpActionResult Test()
{
// Get URL Args for example is 
var args = Request.RequestUri.Query;
// But if the arguments are in the body i don't have idea.
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Web API has a feature which automatically binds argument posted to an action inside a controller. This is called [Parameter Binding](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api). It allows you to simply request the object inside the URL or the body of the POST request, and it does the deserialization magic for you using a thing called Formatters. There is a formatter for XML, JSON, and other known HTTP request types.

For example, lets say I have the following JSON:

```
{
    "SenderName": "David"
    "SenderAge": 35
}
```

I can create an object which matches my request, we'll call it `SenderDetails`:

```
public class SenderDetails
{
    public string SenderName { get; set; }
    public int SenderAge { get; set; }
}
```

Now, by receiving this object as a parameter in my POST action, I tell WebAPI to attempt to bind that object for me. If all goes well, I'll have the information available to me without needing to do any parsing:

```
[Route("api/SenderDetails")]
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Test(SenderDetails senderDetails)
{
    // Here, we will have those details available, 
    // given that the deserialization succeeded.
    Debug.Writeline(senderDetails.SenderName);
}
```

Comment: I am sorry but your answer is an object fixed but i dont have idea name of fields and they change every time. I need an object to get ALL data in body of the post.

Comment: You don't know the object at all? Please share some more information on that. What do you expect to receive?

Comment: Is a bank response, the arguments are changing every time and my program must be ready to get all type of fields and number of this. As I Said in HTTPGET you get all of the url arguments just like that:

 var args = Request.RequestUri.Query;

but in HTTP post i don't have idea.

Comment: Instead of a fixed object, you can receive a `Dictionary<string, object>` and parse it yourself.

Comment: But i don't have idea the name of the field, how load all data in object??

Comment: I like the $_POST of php but in C#, is the solution but i don't have idea to load all body request in a object or variable...

Comment: @David, i think Yuval meaned that if you have `Dictionary<string, object>` as your action's parameter you can treat it like an associative array in PHP. You can iterate over it, find some parameter by key and then cast the value from object to right type (string, int or whatever).

Comment: @doctor_Nick42 I understand you, but what name apply to this var? I type "data" but is null when I call this. On the other hand I am the fields have this syntax Field=Value&Field2=Value2 . I tried with "dynamic data" and if the call have this format:

{
"field":"value"
}

I load on this var, but with dictionary, what name type?

Comment: You can explicitly tell it to bind from the URL using `[FromURL]` attribute. The name shouldn't matter.

Comment: I understand this:

public IHttpActionResult Test([FromBody] Dictionary<dynamic, dynamic>)
{
// Get URL Args for example is 
var args = Request.RequestUri.Query;
// But if the arguments are in the body i don't have idea.
}

but this expected a name.

If this not your idea I don't understand you.

Thanks

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov do you understand me?

Comment: @David, I'm not sure that I understand you well. But if I do - a name of your action's parameter doesn't really matter. Just create your action like that `public IHttpActionResult Test([FromBody] Dictionary<string, object> anyName) {...}` and inside the action you can get your passed values in "associative"-way: `anyName["myFirstProperty"]`. Or, if you don't actually know the names of this object properties - you could itarate over `anyName` with `foreach` loop. Key is a name of property. Sorry if I get you wrong.

Comment: var test = actionContext.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
var test2 = test.Result;

This is result.

Answer (score 0):

If I get you Correctly, in C# you use the `[HttpPost]` attribute to expose a post method.

```
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult Test()
{
// Get URL Args for example is 
var args = Request.RequestUri.Query;
// But if the arguments are in the body i don't have idea.
}
```

Comment: I am sorry, i forgot type the headers of method